# jquery confirmation widgets in magento 2

Tags: jquery, html, magento2

I added jquery confirmation widget to one hyper link. In-spite of clicking cancel and ok in confirmation modal it's redirecting to link. How to restricts it. Here is snippet of my code

html file

```
<td class="col id" > 
  <a class="action edit" id="edit" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getEditUrl($_gridrecord->getEntityId()); ?>" data-ui-id="default-shipping-edit-link">
    <span>
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Edit'); ?>
    </span>
  </a>
```

jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ],
    function($, confirmation) {
         $('#edit').on('click', function(event){
                 confirmation({
             title: 'Some title',
             content: 'Some content',
             actions: {
                 confirm: function(){},
                 cancel: function(){
                   return false;
                 },
                 always: function(){}
             }
           });
       });
      }
);
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You want something like this.

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
    require([
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
        ],
        function ($, confirmation) {
        $('.cancel').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var url = event.currentTarget.href;
            confirmation({
                title: 'Cancel order',
                content: 'Do you wish to cancel this order?',
                actions: {
                    confirm: function () {
                        window.location.href = url;
                    },
                    cancel: function () {},
                    always: function () {}
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The key is to call `event.preventDefault();` and `return false`. You can't do this from a callback. This kills the event, so you need to get the url and save it for the confirm call back. This example is to add a confirm to a cancel order button, checked in magento CE 2.1.7.

Similar answer to Abhishek Dhanraj Shahdeo but I can't edit or comment yet so...

Comment: Yes @chris lingwood you are right, the key is event.preventDefault().

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ],
    function($, confirmation) {
         $('#edit').on('click', function(event){
             event.preventDefault;
                 confirmation({
             title: 'Some title',
             content: 'Some content',
             actions: {
                 confirm: function(){},
                 cancel: function(){
                   return false;
                 },
                 always: function(){}
             }
           });
       });
      }
);
// ]]></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ],
    function($, confirmation) {
         $('#edit').on('click', function(event){
                 confirmation({
             title: 'Some title',
             content: 'Some content',
             actions: {
                 confirm: function(){},
                 cancel: function(){
                   return false;
                 },
                 always: function(){}
             }
           return false;
           });
       });
      }
);
// ]]></script>
```

This will not redirect to your link.

Comment: no it's not working.actully redirecting to link and showing this modal box are parallelly going on .

Comment: anybody can please share sample code for jquery widgets in magento 2 used in hyper link

Answer (score 0):

@vijay b  check this you will get some clue for widget

```
 <a href="#" id="click-header">
    View Video
</a>
<div id="header-mpdal" style="display:none;">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
        <iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" gesture="media" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P45AMKIW0ok" width="560">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: '',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#header-mpdal'));
            $("#click-header").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#header-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );   
</script>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Thanks for you suggestion, above code is use to display a popup in Magento 2 using widget model "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal"

Answer (score 0):

below code will show a confirmation popup you can modify as per your need, add event to show this conformation popup .

```
>     require([
>     'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm' ], function(confirmation) { // Variable that represents the `confirm` widget   //add your event here
> to fire it 
>           confirmation({
>               title: 'Test Conformation Wedget',
>               content: 'Are You Sure',
>               actions: {
>                   confirm: function(){},
>                   cancel: function(){},
>                   always: function(){}
>               }
>           });    // event close here
> 
> });
```

Thanks